# Multiple JPanels - All buttons same size

Tags: java, jpanel, size, jbutton, miglayout

I have a a main panel that contains multiple panels inside. Each 'children' panel contains one (or more) JButtons. Since I am displaying all the panels at the same time, I would like to make all the buttons the same size (to have consistency).

This code illustrates my problem:

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

      // 1st Panel
      JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
      panel1.add(new JButton("button in panel 1"));

      // 2nd Panel
      JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
      panel2.add(new JButton("2nd button"));

      JPanel parent = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap"));
      parent.add(panel1, "pushx, growx");
      parent.add(new JSeparator(), "pushx, growx");
      parent.add(panel2, "pushx, growx");

      f.add(parent);
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

The size of the "button in panel 1" is different from the button in the other panel. Is there an 'easy' way to set their size using the layout? (Hardcoding the size is **NOT** an option).

Comment: The easiest way would be look and feel in java. But it will provide only three possible variation in button size. Check this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html

Comment: I am using Nimbus LAF and i added the sizeVariant property, but im still not getting the desired result.

Comment: How did you changed the size could you please tell me because the link I have shared is java docs which means if you followed the instruction correctly it should work

Comment: This is what I did:  
`JButton b1= JButton("button in panel 1");`    
`b1.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "small");`    
`panel1.add(b1);`    
  
`JButton b2= JButton("2nd button"));`    
`b2.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "small");`    
`panel2.add(b2);`    
and before making the frame visible I added:  
`SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(f);`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't read the document carefully, to demonstrate the use I have written a code. You should not copy the same snippet showed in that link. They have specified that the component you have updating must be passed into [updateComponentTreeUI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#updateComponentTreeUI-java.awt.Component-) method. You can replace the size by replacing the "large" with "small" or "mini".

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Demo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    JFrame frame ;
    JButton btn;
    public Demo()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btn = new JButton("Example");
        btn.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", "large");
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(btn);
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Demo d = new Demo();
    }

}
```